# Mounting drives outside the uses folder with Docker Toolbox for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I may be failing to search SO, but I can't seem to find an answer for this in the last two years, and the ones I've found don't seem to work (unless I'm implementing them wrong).

I'm running Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home, and I'm trying to mount a folder that's outside my User's folder (all my data is on a separate disk). I've mounted the folder into the VM created by docker-machine, but when I try to mount a folder from that drive and SSH into the container, the folder shows as blank. I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  logs:
    driver: local

services:
  proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./api:/var/www
      - logs:/var/logs
  api:
    build:
      context: api/.
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/api
```

The nginx image is basically just loading `nginx:1.15-alpine` and exposes `80` and the api one loads `php:7.2-fpm-alpine` and exposes `9000`.

Are there additional steps to mount something so the docker-machine can use it?

Comment: This is in the Docker Toolbox installation instructions at https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When I said I've tried multiple methods above, I meant I also tried the ones in the docs. I mounted my `F:\www\docker` to `f/docker`, but the docker compose I wrote still doesn't work. I don't know if that's all fine and maybe something is screwed up on my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try the Docker compose, but I think the Docker is the same.

**This doesn't work:**

```
docker run -it -v **./audios**:/audios [docker image]
```

**Meanwhile this command works:**

```
docker run -it -v **/d/audios**:/audios [docker image]
```